# Como capturar e tratar uma Exception na linguagem Swift?

Tags: swift, exceção

Estou com um método de um *framework*, do `AVFunction` que lança uma exceção, mas ao escrever o código que chama esta função não consigo achar qual é exatamente a exceção lançada.

- Como devo proceder para descobrir as possíveis `Exceptions`?
- Como devo tratar esta `Exceptions`?

Comment: Este artigo me ajudou bastante, mas não consegui ainda achar como descobrir a Exceptions possíveis quando estas não estão documentadas e não se tem o código: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch

Comment: Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descobrir as possíveis exceções você tem que ler a documentação do que vai usar. Qualquer outra tentativa não vai resolver.

Existem funções e métodos que documentam suas exceções na própria assinatura o que pode facilitar já que o compilador irá informar que você esquecer de tratar a exceção. Mas este tipo de exceção é controversa, abusada e frequentemente se trata do jeito errado só porque é obrigado.

A captura consciente das exceções é o único meio adequado. Isto só vai ocorrer com a vontade do programador e leitura da documentação.

Há uma [documentação sobre o assunto](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

O jeito mais tradicional é:

```
do {
    try funcao()
    //faz algo aqui
} catch TipoErro.ErroEspecifico { //pega exceção específica
    //faz algo aqui
} catch TipoErro.ErroEspecifico where x == 0 { //exceção filtrada
    //faz algo aqui
} catch { //pega qualquer exceção não especificada anteriormente
    //faz algo aqui
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Swift/Exception.swift).

Em Swift exceção não são tipos especiais, elas podem ser representadas por várias formas. Uma das mais comuns é uma enumeração derivada da [`ErrorType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_ErrorType_Protocol/index.html).

Tem uma série de outras formas de capturar exceções mas esta é a forma mais tradicional. Precisaria de perguntas mais específicas.

Tem algumas formas bem interessantes na linguagem que seria útil ter uma outras linguagens.

Cuidado para não exagerar na captura das exceções que você não pode fazer nada útil. Eu [falo bastante sobre o abuso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:101%20[exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o]).

Comment: Não achei na documentação, fui ao fonte e não achei. claro deve estar em algum lugar, apenas não achei ainda.

Comment: no caso acima parece que não resolve o último catch, o correto seria colocar um traço baixo do tipo } catch _ {}, ai resolve para qualquer excessão.

Comment: eu li a documentação sugerida antes de fazer esta pergunta.

Comment: @Delfino é o que eu sei sobre o assunto. Até poderia escrever mais mas aí eu estaria praticamente trazendo a documentação (não só a *linkada*) pra cá. Até daria para ter mais informações mas a resposta viraria um tutorial completo. Se tiver dúvidas mais específicas, vai perguntando. Eu não terminei de escrever o último `catch`mesmo, arrumei agora mas eu não sei bem quando precisa o do `_` e quando não precisa, existe as duas formas de *catch all*.

Comment: Obrigado @bigown, realmente minhas duvidas são apenas as duas apresentadas, como descobrir as excessões quando não documentadas e não estiverem descritas no código e como tratada-las, a segunda como tratada-las me ajudou bastante, e estou lendo toda a documentação, porém as vezes o problema surge antes de se chegar no ponto da documentação que trata o tema. Mais uma vez obrigado.